# Does Rest Client support NTLM Auth?

Tags: ruby, web-services, rest, ntlm, rest-client

Can [Rest Client](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) do NTLM authentication?

I didn't see any options in the documentation for authentication types:

```
require 'rest_client'

resource = RestClient::Resource.new 'http://website', :auth_type => 'ntlm', :user => 'USERNAME', :password => 'PASSWORD'
results = resource.get
```

`:auth_type => 'ntlm'`  doesn't work, and I couldn't find anything on the documentation or IRC room either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NTLM requirement really narrows down what HTTP software you can use due to it being so specific to Microsoft.

You might want to look at "[NTLM Authentication for Ruby with Typhoeus and Curl](http://speakmy.name/2010/01/19/ntlm-authentication-for-ruby-with-typhoeus-and-curl/)", then look into using [Typhoeus](https://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus) instead of rest-client.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up using: https://github.com/maccman/nestful or just curl.  Believe me I didn't want to use NTLM if I didn't have to :)

Comment: interesting story Greg, sounds like fun over there......here ya go: http://scottw.com/accessing-restful-service-ruby-via - good enough to do everything I need it to do, luckily I won't be accessing the RestAPI behind NTLM too much

Comment: @nictrix - Your link appears to be broken. This worked for me: http://dev.scottw.com/accessing-restful-service-ruby-via

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you can make it do so using the before_execution_proc arg which lets you access the internal Net::HTTP request objects.  If you're using the ruby-ntlm gem it adds a ntlm_auth method to Net::HTTP requests.

```rb
require 'ntlm/http'
require 'rest-client'
require 'json'

# Quick monkey patch to rest client payloads since for some reason Net/NTLM insists on playing payload streams backwards.
class RestClient::Payload::Base
  def rewind
    @stream.rewind
  end
end

auth_proc = ->(req, _args){ req.ntlm_auth(username, domain, password)}
res = RestClient::Request.new(method: :post, url: url, payload: payload}, before_execution_proc: auth_proc ).execute
res
```